# Mysql InnoDB match leading wildcard error

Tags: mysql, innodb, wildcard, match-against

Recently i've changed my DB tabels from MyISAM to InnoDB. Now i've some queries that make use of MATCH and AGAINST.

The following query is an example query that resulting into an error after changing from MyISAM to InnoDB

```
    SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH (test_desc) AGAINST ("*+test" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
    // error: Error Code: 1064. syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*
```

When i remove the * or place it after the "+" sign its working and i getting the same rows as before, but is this correctly?

```
    SELECT * FROM tests WHERE MATCH (test_desc) AGAINST ("+*test" IN BOOLEAN MODE); // works, * after +, BUT IS THIS CORRECT
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` says that the word "test" *should* exist.
`+test` says that "test" must exist.
`test*` looks for anything starting with "test".
`+test*` says that something starting with "test" must exist.

Those are your choices; which do you want?

(MyISAM was somewhat lax about syntax; InnoDB is more strict.)